# Как создать два списка с уникальными числами?

Tags: java

мне надо сделать:  Создать 2 списка из 10 элементов от 1 до 100. Проверить с какой попытки у вас получится создать списки с уникальными значениями.
как правильно это реализовать?
что я делаю:

```
 List<Integer> list1;
List<Integer> list2;
public void createList(){
    int chance = 0;
    while (!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)){
        List<Integer> list1 = Collections.nCopies(10, rand.nextInt(100));
        List<Integer> list2 = Collections.nCopies(10, rand.nextInt(100));
        chance++;
    }
    list1.forEach(System.out::println);
    list2.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println(chance);
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте о перемешивании Фишера-Йетса, и получатся  списки с уникальными значениями с первой попытки

Comment: В каком смысле с уникальными значения в каждом списке? По отдельности или вместе? 10 или 20 уникальных значений? Еще напишите что именно не устраивает в приведенном коде.